# RHEL8: SSH con entorno grafico (Gnome, XFCE)

Tags: interfaz-gráfica, ssh, rhel

Tengo un servidor RHEL al cual me conecto vía SSH.

Ya tengo habilitado el X11 en el ssh e intentado instalar "Server with GUI", "Xfce4", gnome-desktop pero no hay manera de conseguir iniciar el entorno grafico y ya estoy totalmente perdido y es que ya no se si es el xorg el que falla, alguna instalación...

startx:

```
[root@isblccpythp0001 /]# startx xauth:  file /root/.serverauth.37614 does not exist


X.Org X Server 1.20.11 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0 Build Operating System:  4.18.0-240.8.1.el8_3.x86_64 Current Operating System: Linux NOMBRE_MAQUINA
4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 17 07:06:06 EST 2022 x86_64 Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,msdos1)/vmlinuz-4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vgSys-root_lv ro rd.lvm.lv=vgSys/root_lv rhgb quiet ipv6.disable=1 elevator=noop crashkernel=auto Build Date: 09 June 2021 08:57:34AM Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.11-2.el8 Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version. Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown. (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar 23 11:04:03 2022 (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d" (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d" (EE) Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE) (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org  for help. (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information. (EE) (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
```

Gnome:

```
[root@NOMBRE_MAQUINA /]# gnome-session    
    Terminated  
[root@NOMBRE_MAQUINA
```

startxfce4:

```
[root@NOMBRE_MAQUINA /]# startxfce4 /usr/bin/startxfce4: Starting X server


X.Org X Server 1.20.11 X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0 Build Operating System:  4.18.0-240.8.1.el8_3.x86_64 Current Operating System: Linux NOMBRE_MAQUINA 4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Jan 17 07:06:06 EST 2022 x86_64 Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=(hd0,msdos1)/vmlinuz-4.18.0-348.12.2.el8_5.x86_64 root=/dev/mapper/vgSys-root_lv ro rd.lvm.lv=vgSys/root_lv rhgb quiet ipv6.disable=1 elevator=noop crashkernel=auto Build Date: 09 June 2021 08:57:34AM Build ID: xorg-x11-server 1.20.11-2.el8 Current version of pixman: 0.38.4
        Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
        to make sure that you have the latest version. Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
        (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
        (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown. (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Mar 23 11:07:52 2022 (==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d" (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d" (EE) Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found(EE) (EE) Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org  for help. (EE) Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information. (EE) (EE) Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file. xinit: giving up xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused xinit: server error /]#
```

Comment: Te está diciendo que no ha encontrado screens... mira si esto te sirve: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/522256/311686  (aunque no tengo claro lo que pretendes)

Comment: Buenos días,
Disculpa si me explique mal. Es un servidor virtualizado con vmware de empresa del que soy owner al que nos conectamos vía SSH, tanto yo como los tecnicos finales (los usuarios finales harán uso de las aplicaciones django). 
La máquina va a ser usada para implantar scripts Python por gente no tan "técnica" y me pidieron si les podría habilitar un entorno gráfico (ventanas, explorador de ficheros etc...) y lo dí por más sencillo. Instalé mi escritorio gnome porque vengo de ubuntu en mi casa y fue cuando empecé a probar. instalando los grupos, Xfce, GnomeDesktop etc..
Continua-->

Comment: Actualmente tengo instalado "Server with GUI" y "Xfce". Es un sistema virtualizado con vmware:

He seguido el enlace que me has pasado con las 3 instrucciones:

[root@----------------~]# lspci | grep -e VGA -e 3D
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware Device 0711

[root@----------------~]# X -configure
Continua--->

Comment: Veo esto en todo el resultado :
List of video drivers:
        ati
        intel
        nouveau
        qxl
        radeon
        vmware
        modesetting

[root@----------------~]#  nano /root/xorg.conf.new
cambio modsetting por vmware (dummy me dice que no existe)
[root@----------------~]#  X -config /root/xorg.conf.new &

y nada, sigue dando el mismo error :
Continua-->

Comment: (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Thu Mar 24 07:12:07 2022
(==) Using config directory: "/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
(EE)
Fatal server error:
**(EE) no screens found(EE)**
(EE)
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support
         at http://wiki.x.org
 for help.

Comment: No se si me fiaria demasiado de alguien que haga scripts en python pero necesite un entorno gráfico para ponerlos en un servidor... con SSH deberia ser suficiente. De todos modos, poniendo eso del Xfce, etc, sobre un servidor instalado mínimamente con solo SSH, si bien es posible, tambien es propenso a dar errores como te está sucediendo ahora. Si insisten en ello lo que haria seria borrarlo todo e instalar directamente un servidor en modo gráfico, y luego lo limpiaria de porqueria (si instala libreoffice, o cosas de esas), para estar seguro que eso tira.

Comment: Después de instalar el modo gráfico tendras el problema de como acceder a el, pues o bien instalas un servidor VNC o bien algo parecido como [x2go](https://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php) pero eso tambien tiene su miga, o bien hacen correr las X remotamente mediante algun otro sistema, o bien con un teamviewer o anydesk, pero todo eso solo sobrecargará el servidor que segun dices tan solo deberia ejecutar unos python.